# Sorting files from multiple directories in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read and store the file names from a directory to a list.

The folder structure is:

```
dataset
  ├── Type_a
  │   ├── a1_L.wav
  │   ├── a1_R.wav
  │   ├── a2_L.wav
  │   └── a2_R.wav
  └── Type_b
      ├── a1_L.wav
      ├── a1_R.wav
      ├── a2_L.wav
      └── a2_R.wav
```

The expected list output should be:

```py
[[a1_L.wav,a1_R.wav],[a2_L.wav,a2_R.wav],[a1_L.wav,a2_R.wav],[a2_L.wav,a2_R.wav]]
```

Using the following code i am getting the file names but how it can be grouped into a list

```py
import os
    for i, ret in enumerate(os.walk('./dataset/')):
        for i, filename in enumerate(ret[2]):
            print("filename is",filename)
```

Comment: The order of the filenames in a directory is hard is even possible to predict. What gives the order in your example?

Comment: It was created in this manner.. I cant say why its so :(

Comment: So.. sorted by creation date? Or file name?

Comment: @Axe319 By filename

Comment: Not quite sure what's the expected output.. a list of lists (of size 2) with the files that start with the same string? But you have `a1_L.wav` alongside `a2_R.wav`, which would break this rule. So what is the goal here?

Comment: The example is flawed for the simple reason that you can't have two files with the same name in any given directory

Comment: @DarkKnight No two files have same name in a single directory. I have same file names in 2 different directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:-

```
import glob
import os

D={}

for r in glob.glob('./dataset/Type_*/*.wav'):
    t = r.split(os.path.sep)
    if not t[-2] in D:
        D[t[-2]] = []
    D[t[-2]].append(t[-1])
out = []
for v in D.values():
    v.sort()
    for i in range(0,len(v),2):
        out.append([v[i], v[i+1]])
print(out)
```

WARNING: This will fail if there are an odd number of files in any of the Type_* directories

Comment: @DarkKnight This will fail for more entries

Comment: Thank you @Axe319 - I have corrected my answer